# Getting overview of first-level elements of large json file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a very large json file stored in a table with nested entries. I'm trying to get an overview of the data by identifying the first-level element names. Even selecting the first row with `select top 1 src from {big_table};` gives too much output to be analyzed easily.

I wanted to know if there was a way of extracting only the first level of the json array (so with max depth 1). Is there an equivalent command to `show columns in table {name};` for semi-structured data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably OBJECT_KEYS() is what you are looking for: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_keys.html

OBJECT_KEYS() returns an array containing the list of keys in the input object, i.e. your VARIANT-column.

Comment: That's it! Sorry I just saw your answer, but that is indeed what I needed.

Comment: No problem - glad that I helped you :)